# How to add Headers in HTTPContext Response in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a download link in my page, to a file I generate by the user request. Now I want to display the file size, so the browser can display how much is left to download. As a solution, I guess addin a Header to the request would work, but now I don't know how to do it.

Here is my try code:

```cs
public FileStreamResult DownloadSignalRecord(long id, long powerPlantID, long generatingUnitID)
{
    SignalRepository sr = new SignalRepository();
    var file = sr.GetRecordFile(powerPlantID, generatingUnitID, id);
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(file);

    HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());

    return File(stream, "binary/RFX", sr.GetRecordName(powerPlantID, generatingUnitID, id) + ".rfx");
}
```

When I checked on fiddler, it didn't display the Content-Length header. Can you guys help me out?

Answer (score 25):

Try using

```
HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
```

Answer (score 18):

Try `HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", contentLength);`

Comment: The Current doesn't exist inside HttpContext.

Comment: OK, then leave out `Current`. Just use `AppendHeader` instead of `AddHeader` in your original code.

Answer (score 4):

Can you please try the following code and see if that works?

```
public FileStreamResult Index()
{
    HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("test", "val");
    var file = System.IO.File.Open(Server.MapPath("~/Web.config"), FileMode.Open);
    HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
    return File(file, "text", "Web.config");
}
```

"It works on my machine"

And I've tried without the `Content-length` header and Fiddler reports a content length header anyway. I don't think it's needed.

Comment: Your example worked, but when I generate my file, it doesn't happen. ;/

Comment: Have you checked that the stream actually contains anything? `sr.GetRecordFile(..)` returns a `byte[]`, right?

Answer (score 1):

This should solve it as I think there's no need to use the `FileStreamResult`, when you can use the `byte[]` directly.

```
public FileContentResult DownloadSignalRecord(long id, long powerPlantID, long generatingUnitID)
{
    SignalRepository sr = new SignalRepository();
    var file = sr.GetRecordFile(powerPlantID, generatingUnitID, id);

    HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());

    return File(file, "binary/RFX", sr.GetRecordName(powerPlantID, generatingUnitID, id) + ".rfx");
}
```

Note the **FileContentResult** return type.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what else may be wrong there, but that content-length should be the size of the binary, not the string length.

Comment: Actually the length there should be the length of the stream, which would be the length of the binary, right?