# API Endpoint only allows GET when it should take POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I am building a React.js front-end portion of a web application using an already existing back-end that is built with ASP.NET MVC Framework. The method in the API's controller is named Post (which should default it to a post method) and even has the [HttpPost] decorator. I have recently enabled CORS, but I am not sure if that matters.

The API also has Swagger (it's like postman if you haven't used it before) enabled, and when I call the method as POST from the swagger, it will work and return the correct data.

However, when I try to call the method from my UI component, the API endpoint will give a `405 Method Not Allowed` status code.

It says that the method only allows GET, which is baffling since it is supposed to only allow POST and it works that way on swagger or if I manually travel to the URL using a browser. Has anyone had a problem like this using React components or working with ASP.NET MVC/Web API 2?

I am completely stuck...

EDIT:
I am adding the API's method for the post endpoint.

```
[Route("{id}/merchant/SearchMerchants")]
[HttpPost]
[AuthorizeUserPermissionsToken(Cookie)]
public Response Post(Request rq)
{ // I put a breakpoint here to debug
    // some code
}
```

I had to redact a lot of the code but here is the post method.

But I don't think it has to do with the API endpoint.
This is because when I debug, it will not even reach the breakpoint or call the method at all, when I am using the UI. However, it will reach the breakpoint when I travel to the endpoint on the browser or use swagger.

EDIT 2:
EDIT 3: (removed EDIT 2 and moved the original headers to bottom to reduce confusion)

Pre-flight `OPTIONS` request headers

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host: *redacted domain*
Origin:http://localhost:49702
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:49702/FindMerchants
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Nexus 6 Build/LYZ28E) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

response headers to `OPTIONS` request:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:49702
Allow:OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
Content-Length:0
Date:Mon, 07 Aug 2017 18:41:42 GMT
Public:OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
```

then the real `POST` request headers after pre-flight:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:154
Content-Type:application/json
Cookie: *redacted a bunch of cookies*
Host:a *redacted domain*
Origin:http://localhost:49702
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:49702/FindMerchants
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Nexus 6 Build/LYZ28E) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

The real response headers are like so:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true   
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept    
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:49702    
Allow:GET    
Cache-Control:no-cache    
Content-Length:73    
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8    
Date:Mon, 07 Aug 2017 17:58:28 GMT    
Expires:-1    
Pragma:no-cache    
Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0    
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
```

EDIT 4:

```
Request URL:*redacted domain*/380/merchant/SearchMerchant
Request Method:POST
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

EDIT #9999 (jk):

My react component simply calls a custom data service that I wrote, which has a post method like this.

```
post(relativeUrl, data, apiVersion) {
    var url = this.getUrl(relativeUrl, apiVersion);
    var res = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        contentType: 'application/json',    
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        crossDomain: true,
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
    return res;
}
```

I simply pass relativeUrl to fetch a list related to a user account.
Before I make a call that fails (which shows 405), I use this same method to log in and update the global redux state for the app. After updating the global state, I render a different component and use this method again with another relativeUrl to fetch the list. Then I get the error. I also make sure that the login call is finished and returns and updates the state correctly before moving on.

Comment: Are you sure your code is hitting the correct endpoint ? Are you making a POST call from UI ?

Comment: @shyju Yes, I am 100000% confident that it is hitting the correct endpoint and that it is making a POST call.. since the error says POST isn't allowed.

Comment: Can you post the ASP.NET code of the endpoint? The server headers clearly states that it only expect `GET` requests, so something is wrong in your `POST` endpoint.

Comment: You should add `POST` in your CORS, if you have them enabled. Maybe only `GET` is allowed there and not `POST`. This would explain why it would work in Postman or something like that, but not a browser, because those are not run in browsers and thus do not have to conform to CORS rules.

Comment: @DineiRockenbach Hi, I added the ASP.NET code of the endpoint and some more information.

Comment: @Lansana I tried adding the value "POST" into the response headers using customHeaders in my web.config for the API. Headers from the request will now say it allows GET, POST. However, it still says it doesn't allow POST when I actually call the method from the UI.

Comment: @nugget You must add `POST` next to `GET` in the `Allow` header, and it must be set on the response to the `OPTIONS` request that is sent by the browser. Usually, there is a CORS package people use that take care of this and you just set the options for it. [Look here](https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors) for an example of settings CORS on a Go CORS package. As you can see, they allow configuration of `AllowMethods`. One can pass in the methods that they want allowed. My assumption is that whereever you have this sort of config set up, you are missing `POST`.

Comment: @Lansana The response to the `OPTIONS` request sends back a 200 status and the response headers say it allows `OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST`. It passes the pre-flight request test and the actual request is showing the error. I'm not sure if CORS is the problem.

Comment: So let me get this straight: Your endpoint will work in postman/curl/something else, but it won't work in a browser. Is that correct?

Comment: @Lansana Swagger creates a web app that uses the browser to test requests (this is a POST). Also the endpoint will work if I copy + paste the endpoint address and travel to it on the browser (this is a GET request). So I think it works on the browser, just not in the react component that I created. The component is simply sending in a post request to the endpoint using jquery's ajax.

Comment: @Lansana both ways (using swagger or traveling to an endpoint using the browser) will reach the breakpoint within the api method; however, using the UI component to send a request will not reach it.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the full request headers you are sending? Feel free to edit out anything sensitive.

Comment: @Lansana I have done so. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you also add the actual request URL/method, etc that is in the "General" section of chrome dev tools, for each request?

Comment: @Lansana done as well

Comment: You get `Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed`. Are you sure your api handles `POST` for that endpoint? Usually this happens when you have a router that accepts GET, PUT, DELETE, etc for a specific endpoint, but does not accept POST. Please double check this.

Comment: Have you tried creating a custom header response in your server code? Maybe URL rewrite

Comment: @Lansana for sure, it handles post because as i mentioned earlier, the api will work with post when i use swagger. Also, the API works with a previous iteration of the UI that has been implemented with angular.

Comment: @petithomme I am not sure how to do that and how that would help, would you like to explain further? Thanks

Comment: @nugget I'm not used to using ASP.NET so I can't 100% tell you that it works, but I've had a similar problem with Response headers using IIS server. I modified the `web.config` file of the IIS server so that it adds a header to its Response. I'll add the code I used in an Answer so you can see it more clearly.

Comment: @nugget can we see your implementation in your React component? How are you making the HTTP call? The problem must be there given everything else you've said and shown.

Comment: @Lansana updated to show my ajax call within the component

Comment: Can you change `type` to `method` in your jQuery AJAX call options?

Answer (score 1):

To follow my comment,

in web.config file:

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS, HEAD" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: This link would probably help you more for [adding custom headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539342/how-to-add-headers-in-httpcontext-response-in-asp-net-mvc-3) in ASP.NET

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the problem is persisting even after adding this header.

Comment: I actually enabled the CORS through editing the web.config file for custom headers, so I am familiar with it. However, this wasn't the solution :(

Comment: just as un update after editing the web.config, the response header now shows "Allow: GET, POST" as well as `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, HEAD` I am not sure if this is a browser issue though because CORS has no problem with other APIs that I'm using. I am able to `POST` on other API's.

Comment: I traced the failed request to a log as well, but it is not showing any useful information..

Comment: This error doesn't seem normal. You might want to open an issue on the [ÄSP.NET](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues)'s github and place a link to your StackOverflow question. These guys will be able to help you more.