# How to make a Hello World application without HTML tags?

Tags: c#, asp.net, server

I'm used to PHP and I wanted to make a totally empty asp.net page "Hello World" (in the source code) I.E. not "`<html><p>Hello World</p></html>`" I want to totally strip it all out (and possibly manipulate the headers) so the view source is `Hello World`.

This is because I am writing an asp.net throughput environment (basically a triangulation server, to facilitate network security) that effectively redirects so I want to have no outputs that I don't accurately control.

Incidentally this also includes response headers as well. Full Control basically.

This is what I have so far

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're looking at the DOM explorer, not the page source, that's a very different thing.

Comment: What you use is the DOM explorer not the source code. Right click on the page and select `View source`. I bet the tags aren't there.

Comment: oh crumbs... thanks.. M$ edge! bah

Comment: any ideas how to fudge the headers?

Comment: It's not an MS Edge problem at all, Chrome and Firefox will do the same thing. The problem is you looking at the wrong thing.

Comment: FYI: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: no, it is a edge thing, because you can't view source out of the box it reboots and you have to hit F12  I've done this 20 years in every browser imaginable and I don't have view source nor F12 until I rebuild the browser, and I didn't realise that F12 isn't needed once it's bounced the client on/off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically, the browser **do** create "html", "body" etc... basic tags. It's the DOM, created by the browser from what it received.

To explore what you actually received from the server, you can inspect the source. Or better, use developer tools in your browser to look at the network part (to allow you to explore headers as well).

---

To manipulate what you send, you have to manipulate the `context.Response` object.

You can add all the headers you want from there.

from more info, see for example :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse(v=vs.110).aspx

To add headers, see for example this question :

[How to add Headers in HTTPContext Response in ASP.NET MVC 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539342/how-to-add-headers-in-httpcontext-response-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

example:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", contentLength);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you use is the DOM explorer not the source code. Right click on the page and select View source. I bet the tags aren't there.

Headers can be displayed in the [network tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/f12-devtools-guide/network). Just click on the page request in the network tab and you will see details like headers.

Comment: thanks, I know how to view them I want to manipulate them in php it would be `header('Location: http://www.example.com/');` for example