# How to Append Headers in ASP.NET Website using .NET Framework 4.8 like ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-4.8

In ASP.NET core you can append headers using the [Append method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.headers.responseheaders.append?view=aspnetcore-7.0) -

Code example,

```
response.Headers.Append("Some-Header", HeaderValue);
```

Is there a way to achieve the same in .NET Framework 4.8?

Comment: Please try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539342/how-to-add-headers-in-httpcontext-response-in-asp-net-mvc-3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HttpResponse.AppendHeader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.appendheader?view=netframework-4.8.1).

```
response.AppendHeader("Some-Header", HeaderValue);
```